# Passive Speakers connected to a mixer

Tags: speakers, mixer

I have a pair of Yamaha NS-333 speakers that are passive/unpowered speakers. Will I damage them by connecting them to a mixer or will I simply get a lower sound quality without an audio amplifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a power source, you certainly won't damage them, but you also probably won't get a lot of sound out of them either.  Speakers get damaged when they get *too much* power, not when they get insufficient power.

Comment: I thought so, but I just wanted to make sure. thank you!